# How to attach a div to a collapsible navbar

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Basically I have a navbar at the top of the page. This navbar has a collapse functionality, so that the menu is still usable for small screens. I would like to attach a div at the bottom of this collapsible navbar. To be more specific, on the right side of the screen, there would be a red circle which is centered on the border of the navbar.

I am looking for something like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22vSO.png)
The circle is not a button. The collapsible button appears only for small screens (on the right of the navbar)

I have tried many suggestions I found on the Internet. Most of them suggested to give the parent div a relative position and an absolute position to the child div. But it never worked, and the only times it did, it was not responsive.

Here is my current HTML non responsive code

```css
.circle {
  position:absolute;
  <--top:35px;-->
  right:3vw;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background: #d21c2d;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-expand-lg green-background">
    <div class="container-fluid">
       <-- 80 lines of navbar code including a collapse navbar-collapse div -->
    </div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
</nav>
```

So far, the only thing I can do is place the circle for a given size of screen. It is not stable if the screen size changes. It is not with the collapsible mode either.

Thank you very much for your help.
Have a nice day :)

Comment: Can you post an image of your expectation? What is the circle would do, is that a button?

Comment: centred horizontally or vertically?  You may want to use right or top 50% and then translate it back on that axis by -50%

Comment: Wow, using percentage (top:calc(100% - 10px)) seem to work perfectly ! I am sorry for asking a question which has such a simple solution, I am quite new using CSS and bootstrap. Thank you very much for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate it using  `calc`. You can subtract the `px` from total `%`  according to your requirement .

```css
.circle {
  position:absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 10px);
  right:30px;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background: #d21c2d;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-full navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container logo" style="position: relative;">
      <a class="navbar-brand text-left d-block float-left d-xl-flex logo" href="assets/img/kol-logoldpi.svg"><img class="kibrislogo" height="50" src='assets/img/kol-logoldpi2.svg' /></a><button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto text-center">
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Paketler</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="features.html">Kampanyalar</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="pricing.html">sss</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="about-us.html">Hizmet Noktalari</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="contact-us.html"><strong>İLETIŞIM</strong></a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="contact-us.html" style="color: rgba(207,14,14,0.5);">TR/ENG</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <img class="logo" style="position: absolute; right: -7%; height: 70px;" src="assets/img/kol-ccldpi.svg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it by giving by adding your element inside of your navbar and add following properties:

```
.circle{
position:absolute;
z-index: 1001;
right: 35px;
top: 45px; 
width:20px;
height:20px;
background: #d21c2d;
border-radius:50%; 
}
```